# Convertir Base64 a array de byte en android

Tags: java, android, bitmap, byte

Estoy tratando de convertir una imagen que me torna el servidor que viene en codificada en base64, para eso uso este codigo:

```
    byte [] decodedString = Base64.decode(stringImg.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
    Bitmap result = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
    ByteArrayOutputStream aOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    result.compress( Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, aOutputStream );
    return aOutputStream.toByteArray();
```

Aveces funciona y otras no, cuando no funciona genera un `NullPointerException` en esta linea `result.compress( Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, aOutputStream )` No se por que esta pasando, si alguien sabe el porque o de otra forma de como hacerlo, se lo agradecería

Comment: Valida que solo debe obtener el Bitmap si stringImg.getBytes() es diferente a null

Answer (score 0):

El error `NullPointerException` que obtienes en este punto de tu código:

```
result.compress( Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, aOutputStream );
```

esto es debido a que el bitmap que tratas de generar no existe, debes revisar que en verdad obtengas bytes en `stringImg.getBytes()` para que se pueda crear correctamente el array de bytes:

```
byte [] decodedString = Base64.decode(stringImg.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
```